# databases Ms access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have created database for employees in access 2007.
Employee table

Employee code (primary key)
Name
Department
Etc

Leave record table

Employee code (foreign key)
From date
To date 
Number of days etc

Now, I am facing the issue of how to enter multiple leaves under one employee code because code is primary key, and it won't let me enter multiple employee code.

Answer (score 0):

[Employee_code] should not be the Primary Key for the [Leave_record] table. You need that field in the table as a *Foreign Key* (as you have noted), but it should not be the Primary Key because the Primary Key cannot contain duplicates.

Consider adding an AutoNumber field named [Leave_record_ID] to the [Leave_record] table and make that the Primary Key. Or, you could use a *composite* Primary Key based on the [Employee_code] and [From_date] fields.